# Amazon SQS(Simple Queuing Service) Speed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

What is speed of Amazon SQS(Simple Queuing Service) for queuing, in format like n MB/KB per second.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recently at AWS:reInvent the Messaging Team did a demo of SQS throughput using EC2 and SQS. And SQS was able to achieve tens of thousands of messages a second on a single EC2 machine.

The video is available here:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zwLC5xmCZUs#t=22m53s

If you are using EC2 micro or small instances and a single threaded application, you won't be able to get those kinds of numbers. We have customers who are regularly making more requests than the numbers show in the demo app. The speed of SQS mostly depends on how scalable you write your senders and receivers.

Hope this helps.

Comment: (A) it's a video from 2012 (B) it doesn't answer the question. If someone will have 10,000 micro EC2 for example, will there be a limit to the SQS?

Answer (score 4):

If speed means throughput, 10s of thousands per second is easily achievable. Adam Warski did some detailed benchmarking here

http://www.warski.org/blog/2014/06/benchmarking-sqs/

If speed means latency, expect to see 50th percentiles of ~20ms and 99th percentiles of 200ms between inserting and being able to read. See Paul Colby's analysis here:

http://colby.id.au/benchmarking-sqs/